# GitLab custom issue tracker link to reference tickets in Rally

Tags: gitlab, rally

I am trying to create reference tickets links in GitLab when we enter any Rally ticket number in the commit message or merge title in GitLab. The sample ticket number in Rally looks like TA31950

We can link with ticket number using https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/search?keywords= [Ticket number]

Example: https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/search?keywords=TA31950 (This will directly open a ticket in Rally)

When I am mentioning ticket number in GitLab commit message or merge title in a format -, i.e. ANYTHING and ID separated by a hyphen, then automatically a link gets created. It's working fine. But I want to remove the hyphen as a ticket as in Rally tickets there is no hyphen.

Sample: (Hover mouse over the ticket number after opening below GitLab branches commits)
https://gitlab.com/deepaklearner/test/-/commits/master

As per [documentation of GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/custom_issue_tracker.html):

Issues are referenced with - (for example, PROJECT-143), where  can be any string in CAPS, and  is a number used in the target project of the custom integration.

The problem is in Rally, the ticket number is not in format -

GitLab custom issue tracker to reference tickets in Rally without the hyphen

How to search for tickets in rally:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/search?keywords=TA31950

If I am entering the ticket number with hyphen separator, it's working fine. PFB snapshot how I configured:

[image]